# unlist to produce a vector of same length

Tags: r, list, vector, character

I have a list like this:

```
lst <- list(a = c("y"), b = c("A", "B", "C"), c = c("x1", "x2"))
lst

> lst
$a
[1] "y"

$b
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$c
[1] "x1" "x2"
```

If I `unlist` it, I get:

```
unlist(lst)
> unlist(lst)
   a   b1   b2   b3   c1   c2 
 "y"  "A"  "B"  "C" "x1" "x2"
```

How can I get a vector like:

```
        a         b         c 
      "y" "A, B, C"  "x1, x2"
```

Edit: 
A similar question [Convert a list of lists to a character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624289/convert-a-list-of-lists-to-a-character-vector) was answered previously. The answer proposed by @42_ `sapply( l, paste0, collapse="")` could be used with a small modification: `sapply( l, paste0, collapse=", ")`. Ronak Shah's `sapply(lst, toString)` to my question is a little more intuitive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list of lists to a character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624289/convert-a-list-of-lists-to-a-character-vector)

Comment: Thanks. This is slightly different from the previous question. A small modification of those answers would solve my problem. The solution `sapply(lst, toString)` by Ronak Shah is simpler than previous answers.

Comment: A separator of `""` and one of `", "` don't seem substantially different

Comment: For new R users, it is difficult to get our heads around functions like `apply` and `paste`. A smallest difference may take a long time to work out. Ronak Shah's solution directly answers my question, simple and straightforward. I have learned something new and useful from this answer which could also help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `toString` to collapse all the elements in every list into a comma-separated string.

```
sapply(lst, toString)
#     a       b       c 
#    "y" "A,B,C" "x1,x2"
```

which is same as using `paste` with `collapse` argument as `","`

```
sapply(lst, paste, collapse = ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

`unlist(Map(function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ","),lst))`

Or

`unlist(lapply(lst,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ",")))`

Or use `purrr` package

`purrr::map_chr(lst,paste0,collapse = ",")`

Answer (score 1):

we can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_chr(lst, str_c, collapse=",")
```