# List of characters to character vector

Tags: r, string, list

I would like to convert a named list of characters like

```
stringlist = list("list1" = list("a","b",c("a","b")), 
                  "list2" = list("c","d",c("c","d")))
```

into a character vector

```
[1] "a"  "b"  "ab" "c"  "d"  "cd"
```

where the list objects of length > 1 are combined into a single element in the resulting character vector. The solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624289/convert-a-list-of-lists-to-a-character-vector) is

```
sapply(stringlist, paste0, collapse="")
```

which returns

```
              list1               list2 
"abc(\"a\", \"b\")" "cdc(\"c\", \"d\")"
```

so I was wondering whether there is an elegant and short solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a nested list `unlist` it one level and then use the solution that you have.

```
unname(sapply(unlist(stringlist, recursive = FALSE), paste0, collapse = ''))
#[1] "a"  "b"  "ab" "c"  "d"  "cd"
```

Comment: Else use argument `use.names` in `unlist` directly instead of adding `unname` function ie. `sapply(unlist(stringlist, recursive = F, use.names = F), paste0, collapse = "")`

Answer (score 4):

Using `rapply`.

```
unname(rapply(stringlist, paste, collapse=""))
# [1] "a"  "b"  "ab" "c"  "d"  "cd"
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `rrapply`

```
library(rrapply)
unname(rrapply(stringlist, f = paste, collapse="", how = 'unlist'))
#[1] "a"  "b"  "ab" "c"  "d"  "cd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option is using nested `sapply` (but not as straightforward as the `r(r)apply` method)

```
> c(sapply(stringlist, function(x) sapply(x, paste0, collapse = "")))
[1] "a"  "b"  "ab" "c"  "d"  "cd"
```